# Doing MLE when data is missing not at random

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, missing-data, censoring

Suppose $X, Y, S$, and $Y=f_\theta(X), S=f_\phi(Y), S \in \{0,1\}$. For $n$ data samples, the $y_i$ is only observed for those who have $s_i=1$.
That is, we have $\{x_i, y_i, s_i=1\}_{i=1}^{l}$ and $\{x_i,  s_i=0\}_{i=l}^{n}$ .

If I want to estimate $\theta$ with $MLE$, what should I do?

I think [image] is not the unbiased estimation, because the likelihood function if $P(Y|X,S=1)$, which doesn't equal $P(Y|X)$.

- **My attempt:**

maximize likelihood $P(X|Y, S=1)$, which equals $P(X|Y)$ as following:
[image]

- **My question:**

1. Is my solution right? Is the $\theta$ estimated by $P(X|Y)$ unbiased?
2. Are the $p(x^i), p(y^i)$ in the last line the probability for all the population or the selected population where $s_i=1$?

Please give me some advice or point out my error. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify the first paragraph should be: That is, we have $\{x_i, y_i, s_i=1\}_{i=1}^{l}$ and $\{x_i,  s_i=0\}_{i=l}^{n}$. correct?

Comment: @bdeonovic Yes, thank you and I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

A generic modelling would rely on the observed likelihood
$$\prod_{i;\ s_i=1}p_\theta(y_i,S_i=1|x_i)\times \prod_{i;\ s_i=0}\int p_\theta(y_i,S_i=0|x_i)\,\text dy_i$$
(which integrates out the unobserved $Y_i$'s in the second part) and a potential EM approach would treat the $Y_i$'s when $s_i=0$ as missing data.

Comment: Thank you so much, but could you give me more explanation about the second term?

Comment: Thank you so much, and I can understand the likelihood you post now. I have another question. I wrote a simple demo in R, and I found that when the likelihood is $\prod_{i; s_i=1} (p_\theta(y_i|x_i) /  \int p_\theta (y_i|x_i) p(x_i)d x_i) $, the estimated $\theta$, that is,$ ( \alpha, \beta)$ is unbiased. I think that can prove my posted solution, am I right? I set $X\sim N(-2,1), Y=sign(\alpha X + \beta), S=sign(\sigma Y +\mu)$ . Could you please help me check it? I really appreciate your reply.

Comment: If you use _only_  the $Y_i$'s such that $S_i=1$ and the exact conditional distribution $p(y_i, S_i=1|x_i)$, maximum likelihood is valid. (I would not use the term unbiased as MLE is in general biased in the usual sense.) But I do not understand why you would divide by this integral in $x_i$.

Comment: Hi, I used $\int p_\theta(y_i|x_i)p(x_i)dx_i$ to calculate $p(y_i)$, and the numerator is $p_\theta(y_i|x_i)$. I use "unbiased" because I found the estimated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is very close to the truth. But I am not sure why. I think it meet my posted solution, but I quite doubt about its correctness.

Comment: I still fail to understand why you would integrate in $x_i$ when observing $X_i$.

Comment: I think I integrate over $x_i$ to get $p(y_i)$ as $P(Y)=\sum_X P(Y|X)P(X)$